# Autodesk Forge API with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, autodesk

```
class MyClass extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct(){
    
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('ForgeApi');
    }



    public function save(){
    
        $this->func("test_bucket_name");
    
    }//save

    
}//End of class
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**
Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

I am trying to integrate forge API with coeigniter

Can you please help me to resolve this issue or at least put me on the right path.

Thx

Comment: did you load session library somewhere? manual or autoload?

Comment: Session library is already loaded in autoload.php. This issue is there because ForgeAPI.php has been included.  I include Forge SDK by Autodesk in ForgeAPI.php file